# Как вывести массив $_POST

Tags: php

Например я делаю запрос post

```
curl -d 'qqqqq' http://localhost:9999/php
```

Вывожу запрос

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Вывод следующий

```
array(1) {
  ["qqqqq"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

По идее `$_POST` массив, но когда я пытаюсь по нему пройтись

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $elem)
{
    echo $elem;
}
?>
```

Никакого вывода нет. Почему?

Comment: Потому что, очевидно, значение элемента `qqqqq` является пустой строкой (это отчётливо видно по выводу `string(0) ""` в var_dump'e), и echo выводит эту пустую строку, то есть выводит ничего

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
```

qqqqq - у вас ключ, значение которого пустая строка.. конкретно в вашем случае

Обратите внимание на postman

Answer (score 0):

Как уже сказали, `qqqqq` увас - ключ массива, а внутри - пустая строка.

Если Вам нужно получить значение этого ключа, то нужно действовать следующим образом:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
   echo 'Ключ: '.$key.' Значение: '.$value;
}
```

Темерь, к примеру, если массив $_POST сделать примерно следующий:

`

```
array(
"q" => "1",
"w" => "2"
)
```

Получим следующее:

```
Ключ: q Значение: 1
Ключ: w Значение: 2
```